# Obtaining a cashier's check from an international airport

Tags: united-states, international, cashier-check

I will be looking to buy a cashier's check from Seaway Bank located at Chicago's O' Hare International Airport. What information would I need to provide about the payee to obtain the cashier's check. Just the name, or something else as well? Please also note that I'm an international student who'll be travelling to the United States. Would the bank provide me, an international, with a cashier's check, if I pay the bank upfront with cash.

Comment: Maybe ones at an airport will be different, but in my experience I've needed an account at a bank to get a cashier's check from them.

Comment: @ceejayoz True. I hope someone can address this issue.

Comment: Could you explain why you need to convert from cash to cashier's check? Maybe we can offer an alternative that solves your issue.

Comment: @ceejayoz presumably it's for his apartment, as described in [his other question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/96892/13817).

Comment: @Kevin Correct.